# Flutter Firebase Crashlytics with unclear Fatal Exeption

Tags: flutter, dart, crashlytics

I am using **Crashlytics** for my Flutter-App and it gives me multiple issues, where the app apparently crashed for some users, but I have absolutely no idea why and I can't get anything off from the logs...

This is what Crashyltics is giving me:

[image]

So it says

> Null check operator used on a null value. Error thrown while handling a pointer data packet.

But it's not giving me any information about where exactly this error was thrown. Has anybody experienced something similar?

How can I fix this? Let me know if you need any more info!